# How to use the latest Java SE version?

Tags: java, sdk

I had Java SE (version 8) installed on my computer (Windows 10). Now, I have downloaded version 13. I have also added the path

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.1\bin

in Environment Variables -> System Variables -> Path

But still when I write

> java -version

on cmd, I get the path of the older version.

> java version "1.8.0_231"
>
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_231-b11)
>
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.231-b11, mixed mode)

Upon writing

> where java

I got the following result

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe
>
> C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe
>
> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.1\bin\java.exe

In the environment variables ->

I get the following relevant paths:

> C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath
>
> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.1\bin

Note: doesn't have the path of Java 8 as I deleted it.

Interestingly, I am still able to run the Java code.

I am confused now..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.1\bin` to the top in the list of environment variables. Then, open a new command prompt and execute `java -version`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don’t explicitly add the directory to your PATH environment variable, you get the java binary  installed at system level.

This was typically done by the browser java plugin installer, which is not used anymore so you get to keep the old version. I would suggest uninstalling it.